# Geocoding street addresses with no suffixes

Tags: python-3.x, geocoding, geocode, geopy

Situation:
I have been tasked with geocoding and plotting addresses to a map of a city for a friend of the family.

I have a list of over 400 addresses. Included in those addresses are PO Boxes and addresses with Street Number, Direction, Street Name, Street Suffix (some do not have this), City, and Zip Code.

I tried to geocode all of the addresses with Geopy and Nominatim.

Issue:

I noticed that those addresses without street suffixes and PO Boxes could not be geocoded.

What I have done:

I have read most posts dealing with addresses, read the Geopy notes and google searched until the cows came home.

I ended up stumbling across a geocoding website that PO boxes could not be mapped and that street suffix is required for mapping.

http://www.gis.harvard.edu/services/blog/geocoding-best-practices

Question:

Is there a way to search for the street suffix of each street that is missing a street suffix?

Is there another free service or library that can be utilized other than Nominatim and Geopy that can utilize the information I have and not require me to look up each individual street suffix in google maps?

Please advise!

Comment: Are the address just strings, or do you know exactly which ones don't have a suffix?

Comment: The addresses are just strings. I can figure out which ones do not have a suffix, by running them through the script. I setup my code to return all errors as NaN.

Comment: as in an error means the geolocator couldn't find the address (perhaps because it is a PO box), and then returns an error? You can't then, arbitrarily insert st. or rd.?

Comment: Correct. If the Geolocator could not find the address, then it returns NaN. I could insert St. or Rd. in the event of an error. I just want to see if there is a geolocator out there or library that determines the suffix without having to create it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that using Geopy with Google's API can find the correct addresses that services like Nominatim, OpenCage and OpenMapquest will not fine.

There is one downside, the autocomplete can make it hard to determine if the address is the correct address.

Answer (score 0):

First, speaking to the need to find an address that is missing a street suffix, you need to use address completion from an address validation service. Services that do address validation/verification use postal service data (and other data) and match address search inputs to real addresses. If the search input is not sufficiently specific, address validation services may return a handful of potential matches. Here is [an example of a non-specific address](https://smartystreets.com/demo/api?auth-id=21102174564513388&prefix=4770%20Lincoln%20Oak%20Hill&#us-autocomplete) (missing the State, zip code, and the street suffix) that returns two real addresses that match the search input. SmartyStreets can normally fill in the missing street suffix.

Second, speaking to the PO Box problem: some address services can give you geocode information, as well as other information that you may believe isn't available. For instance, [this search shows the SmartyStreets service](https://smartystreets.com/demo/api?auth-id=21102174564513388&candidates=10&street=PO%20Box%20115%2C%20Salt%20Lake%20City%20UT&#us-street) matching a PO Box number (that I just made up) to the local post office. The latitude and longitude in the response JSON corresponds to the post office when I search it on Google Maps.

Third, speaking to the problem of having a list of addresses: there are various address services that allow batch processes. For instance, it's a fairly common feature to allow a user to upload a spreadsheet of addresses. Here is the [information page](https://smartystreets.com/docs/plugins/smartylist) for SmartyStreets' tool.

There are multiple address services that can help you do all or some of these things. Depending on the service, they will provide some free functionality or have free tiers if you don't do very many searches. I am not aware of a service that does everything you need for free. You could probably use a few services together, like the Google Maps API to Geopy, etc, but it would take effort to code up a script to put them all together.

---

Full disclosure: I worked for SmartyStreets.